# Read data from a pandas Dataframe and create a tree and represent it as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'parent id': [0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4], 
                    'id' : [1,2,3,4,11,12,13,16,14,15,41,42,43]})
```

I want to use this data to create a tree and then represent the tree as a dictionary like this:

```
tree = {0: [1, {2: [{3: [14, 15]}, {4: [41, 42, 43]}, 11, 12, 13, 16]}]})
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in the of the object/numbers in the list isn't exactly like yours, but I'm guessing that doesn't matter.

```py
items = df[~df['id'].isin(df['parent id'])].groupby('parent id').apply(lambda x: {x['parent id'].iloc[0]: x['id'].tolist()})
df[df['id'].isin(df['parent id'])].apply(lambda x: items[x['parent id']][x['parent id']].append(items[x['id']]), axis=1)
tree = items.iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> tree
{0: [{2: [{4: [41, 42, 43]}, {3: [14, 15]}, 11, 12, 13, 16]}, 1]}
```

Output (formatted):

```
{
    0: [
        {
            2: [
                {
                    4: [
                        41,
                        42,
                        43
                    ]
                },
                {
                    3: [
                        14,
                        15
                    ]
                },
                11,
                12,
                13,
                16
            ]
        },
        1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. It works like a charm. I have a question though. How to find the leaves in that tree?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't exactly know what you mean. :( What are you trying to get?

Comment: By "leaves" are you referring to one of the arrays?

Comment: I mean the ones that don't have children (e.g. 1, 41, 42, 43, etc)

Comment: I need to replace their values later on

Comment: You want to be able to do something like `j[0][2][4]` to get the numbers in `4` (child of `2` (child of `0`))? (hope you understand that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239591/discussion-between-nestor-desabille-and-user17242583).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is primarily a tree traversal problem, a recursive approach using [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/install.html) may end up being a more intuitive solution.

We can create a [DiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) from `df1` using [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html). Then do a recursive traversal rooted at a given node like 0:

```
def build_dict(graph, root):
    if not graph[root]:  # root has no children
        return root  # Return current root
    return {
        root: [
            # Build dict for each child of current root
            build_dict(graph, child_node) for child_node in graph[root]
        ]
    }


T = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df1, source='parent id', target='id', create_using=nx.DiGraph
)
res = build_dict(T, root=0)
```

`res`:

```
{0: [1, {2: [{3: [14, 15]}, {4: [41, 42, 43]}, 11, 12, 13, 16]}]}
```

The benefits of this approach are the access to a [networkx DiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) with all of the graph related computation and visualisation features it offers. However, this is a recursive solution which, while intuitive, has all of the standard drawbacks.

---

Setup used:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'parent id': [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 16, 14, 15, 41, 42, 43]
})
```